# Symfony2 - Class XXX not found

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have deployed a Symfony Application to a one.com server. I wrote a Mail service that sends my emails via SwiftMailer.

Now, since one.com has no phar-extensions allowed, composer cannot be updated via ssh. So I generated the classmap locally with

```
composer update -o
```

Whenever I try to get the Mail service, the application throws an error:

> Fatal error: Class
>   'Stocksolutions\ShopBundle\DependencyInjection\Mail' not found in
>   /customers/4/b/b/stocksolutions.be/httpd.www/releases/20150204201140/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php
>   on line 3602

I have searched the composer classmap and the class that isn't found is inside it:

```
'StockSolutions\\ShopBundle\\DependencyInjection\\Mail' => $baseDir . '/src/StockSolutions/ShopBundle/DependencyInjection/Mail.php'
```

Furthermore, I can get other services in the container, f.e. those from the FOSUserBundle, but getting my custom services throws an error. Also, I don't get these errors when testing locally..

Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't UPDATE on the production server, because that would pull new versions that you didn't test with. Run `composer install` and commit and deploy that `composer.lock` file into your project. Your deployment may use SSH to copy from a local machine to remote, with all dependencies and autoloading installed. If it works locally, it should work remote.

Comment: It doesn't work when I don't generate the classmap. Then I get this `Class not found`-error on the homepage (with a different class). Maybe something worth knowing is that the application is located in a subfolder and referred to through an htaccess file.. Then again, the path to the class in the classmap is correct and the file is in place.. So I can't really wrap my head around this..

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache after you generated the classmap ? This would update `appDevDebugProjectContainer.php` and maybe your problem will go away.

Comment: Yes I have, this did not change anything.

Comment: You dont have to use `composer` as a phar you can checkout the source and use it that way either installing it somewhere or including it directly in your project...

Comment: I have. I manually uploaded the vendors, including the classmap, but it still doesn't recognize my custom helpers (which is weird, considering all of the other classes are properly loaded)

Comment: The stuff thats not loading does it actually use the `classmap` feature of autoload in your composer.json or does it use one of the `psr` loading strategies? Cause most of the symfony ones are going to use `psr-*`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's case-sensitive problem.

Your error:

> Fatal error: Class
>   'Stock**s**olutions\ShopBundle\DependencyInjection\Mail' not found

Small letter `s` in `Stocksolutions` namespace for PSR forces to search for the file `/src/Stock**s**olutions/ShopBundle/DependencyInjection/Mail.php`, but exist `/src/Stock**S**olutions/ShopBundle/DependencyInjection/Mail.php`.

On local system likely Windows, where the path/filenames case-insensitive, error does not occur.

P.S. Most likely a typo in class namespace is in the bundle service description (`services.yml`/`services.xml`).

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I couldn't get my head around this!